# Get the value by passing key to array of object in react and lodash

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I have an object which looks like :

```
let result = {
    status: 'success',
    Node: {
      Node: [{
        name:'A',
        url: 'homeURL'
      },{
        name:'b',
        url: 'AboutURL'
      },{
        name:'c',
        url: 'LogoURL'
      }]
    },
    resultNode: [{
        UserInfo:'AboutURL',
        type:'data'
    }]
}
```

Now here I am trying to get the object from the Node array which has the url key value and from resultNode object UserInfo key value same

So I want to return.

```
{        name:'b',
        url: 'AboutURL'
      }
```

This object.

What I tried is using lodash

```
result?.Node_.find((node) => {
   result?.resultNode.map((resultnode) => {
         return resultnode.UserInfo === node.url 
})
})
```

But this does not work, How to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this without lodash:

```
let rs = result.Node.Node.filter((node)=>
  result.resultNode.some((resNode)=>resNode.UserInfo === node.url)
);
```